# Coudn't connect to daemon

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod, daemon, synchronization

Wallet do not synchronizing because he couldn't connect to daemon. Win 10. Restore height is 2150000.

I tried:

- Reinstall GUI (I had used latest version (17.4) before, but anyway)
- Start monerod
- Resync whole blockchain (I nearly download it, but it stopped at 7k blocks before syncing and don't want to sync again).
- Start monerod x2 (it automatically closes after "initizatiling core" after 1 second)

Bitmonero says:

> 2020-11-23 18:02:57.625   8732    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
> 2020-11-23 18:02:57.626 8732    INFO    global  src/daemon/main.cpp:293 Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.1.3-release)
> 2020-11-23 18:02:57.626 8732    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:53    Initializing cryptonote protocol...
> 2020-11-23 18:02:57.627 8732    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:58    Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
> 2020-11-23 18:02:57.628 8732    INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:63    Initializing core...
> 2020-11-23 18:02:57.629 8732    INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:515 Loading blockchain from folder C:\Games\MoneroBlockchain\lmdb ...
> 2020-11-23 18:02:57.762 8732    INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:690 Loading checkpoints
> 2020-11-23 18:02:57.763 8732    INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:73    Core initialized OK
> 2020-11-23 18:02:57.764 8732    INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:63 Initializing p2p server...
> 2020-11-23 18:02:58.030 8732    FATAL   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:1072  Error starting server: Failed to bind IPv4 (set to required)
> 2020-11-23 18:02:58.031 8732    INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:94    Deinitializing core...
> 2020-11-23 18:02:58.369 8732    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:75    Stopping cryptonote protocol...
> 2020-11-23 18:02:58.370 8732    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:79    Cryptonote protocol stopped successfully
> 2020-11-23 18:02:58.371 8732    ERROR   daemon  src/daemon/main.cpp:361 Exception in main! Failed to initialize p2p server.

It happens every time after this:

> 2020-11-23 15:55:26.475   [P2P9]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1600    Synced 2229820/2236981 (99%, 7161 left)
> 2020-11-23 16:11:57.270 [P2P6]  WARNING global  src/p2p/net_node.inl:1989   No incoming connections - check firewalls/routers allow port 18080
> 2020-11-23 17:11:58.097 [P2P0]  WARNING global  src/p2p/net_node.inl:1989   No incoming connections - check firewalls/routers allow port 18080
> 2020-11-23 17:49:22.980 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:80 p2p net loop stopped
> 2020-11-23 17:49:23.150 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:84 Stopping core RPC server...
> 2020-11-23 17:49:28.152 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/daemon.cpp:227   Node stopped.
> 2020-11-23 17:49:28.178 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:96 Deinitializing core RPC server...

Comment: ERA LA PORTA OCCUPATA E STATO FACILE
GRAZIE

Comment: This exact what I get too. The problem is, **do not start the monerod before starting the GUI**.
The GUI starts the daemon a second time, if it already runs or not.
The first instance blocks the ports for the second.
That's a flaw in the GUI. A logical error within the GUI from my point of view.

Answer (score 0):

It could be two things.

1. Your firewall is blocking the daemon from working. Try allowing a new firewall for monerod.exe
2. There is something that is using port 18080. If you know what program uses this port, close it before starting monerod.exe